# Youtube embedded video keeps hiding my JavaScript popup dialogs

Tags: javascript

I tried playing with z-index, and also tried setting the wmode to "opaque". Nonthing worked..

It keeps hiding my popup dialogs..

Here is the current iframe code

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="450" height="297" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/glqpoDfuAwk" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out below, using "embed" and opaque wmode solves the problem. But I cannot find any solution for YouTube's new style of embedding using iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flash embed code still works **([Demo](http://jsbin.com/oyutu4/2))**:

```
<object width="640" height="385">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/vx2u5uUu3DE"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/vx2u5uUu3DE" 
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always"
         allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385" wmode="opaque"></embed>
  </object>
```

Comment: Yes, but how can it be done in YouTube new style of embedding with iframe?

Comment: Man, they're just doing the same embed in the iframe. :) But you have less control with that style as you've noticed.

Answer (score 1):

You can still add the wmode when dealing with an iframe.
Add

```
?wmode=transparent
```

to the iframe src-parameter.
This fixed it for me.